# IBatteryStats.Stub.asInterface( ServiceManager.getService( batterystats)) don't have permission

Tags: android

```
 mBatteryInfo = IBatteryStats.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(BatteryStats.SERVICE_NAME));

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
```

That's the BatteryStatsHelp, I have that permission in manifest,but there still has a error

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10160 does not have android.permission.BATTERY_STATS.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at com.android.internal.app.IBatteryStats$Stub$Proxy.getStatisticsStream(IBatteryStats.java:1143)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper.getStats(BatteryStatsHelper.java:755)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper.load(BatteryStatsHelper.java:746)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper.getStats(BatteryStatsHelper.java:236)
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper.refreshStats(BatteryStatsHelper.java:323)
   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper.refreshStats(BatteryStatsHelper.java:316)
   at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsHelper.refreshStats(BatteryStatsHelper.java:296)
   at com.example.administrator.vhtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
```

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: 23 , but this api includes the hide api and internal package, because the general api has hided those packages

Comment: and I also use the 24, and that is the standard, I use reflect to use this api, that also has that error, say    does not have android.permission.BATTERY_STATS

Comment: See [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for getting permissions above or on API level 23

Comment: I'll try it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just simply get this permission. Google is successively closing down the access to private system API with each newer version. The permission model introduced in API 23 was a key and starting point for making such process possible.
Your application must be a system app (signed with the same certificate as system apps) in order to omit `SecurityException`.

If you want to know how to omit this and make it work only on emulator devices, look into [TestButler](https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler) project. They have an interesting [approach](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/08/introducing-and-open-sourcing-test-butler--reliable-android-test) for it.

Comment: thanks  let me try.   that means my app can't get that permission from the manifest .